# How to compare field changes using powershell to iterate thru the version history

Tags: powershell, version-history

I need to be able to to notify users daily whenever an update to a list item has changed, and give them a list of fields that have been changed.  I am using powershell to do this, and send out an email with the Daily Summary of any items and the changes that have been made.  I need to compare a specific version to the previous version field by field to see what has changed.  I am just using brute force to do this by iterating over all the fields in each version and comparing it to the previous version.  It seems like there should be a more elegant way to do this within PowerShell.  Anyone know of a better solution?

Here is example code for iterating thru the versions:

```
$x=1 #set to 1 for the 2nd index of the version array
foreach ($version in $listitem.Versions | Sort-Object Created -Descending)
{
    if ($x > $listitem.Versions.Count)
    {
        #exit.  The value of x is outside the array
        break
    }

    if ($version.Created.ToShortDateString() -eq  $currentdate.ToShortDateString())
    {
        foreach ($field in $version.Fields)
        {
            if ($field.ShowInVersionHistory -and ($version[$field] -ne $listitem.Versions[$x][$field]))
            {
                #Field has changed so add it to the list if not already in the list
                if (!($changedFields -match $field))
                {
                    if($changedFields.Length -eq 0 )
                    {
                        #first item in list
                        $emailNeeded = $true
                        $changedFields += $field
                    }
                    $changedFields += ", $field"
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        #Exit loop if we hit a date before current date
        break
    }
    $x++
}
```